# Making a conditional variable based on last observation in temporal data

Tags: r

```
ID T V1 
1 1 1 
1 2 1 
2 1 0
2 2 0
3 1 1
3 2 1
3 3 1
```

I need a to make two variables from these data. The first needs to be a 1 on the last observation *only* when V1 = 1, and then a 1 on the last observation for all cases. Ideal final product:

```
ID T V1 v2 v3
1 1  1   0  0
1 2  1   1  1
2 1  0   0  0
2 2  0   0  1
3 1  1   0  0
3 2  1   0  0
3 3  1   1  1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in the package **dplyr**, you can group your data according a variable (according `ID` in your case) and make operations for each group. As one of your column (`T`) already counts the rank of each observation (within each group), you can combine with the function `n()` which returns the number of rows of each group in order to obtain what you want.

Suppose your data are in the dataframe `df` :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    v2 = 1 * (`T` == n()),
    v3 = 1 * (`T` == n()) * (V1 == 1) 
  )

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID     T    V1    v2    v3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0     0
2     1     2     1     1     1
3     2     1     0     0     0
4     2     2     0     1     0
5     3     1     1     0     0
6     3     2     1     0     0
7     3     3     1     1     1
```

Comment: This works perfectly on the test data provided above as you demonstrate, it was the direction I was hoping to go, but I was missing the n() command! But on my data, I get v2 and v3 as all 0 values. The data are sorted by Time instead of by ID, so I amended the code to add:  df %>% 
arrange(df, desc(T)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    v2 = 1 * (`T` == n()),
    v3 = 1 * (`T` == n()) * (V1 == 1) 
  )

and still no dice. Any thought of what could be producing the differences in outcomes?

Comment: first, change the name of the column `T`, because in a R script, T is for TRUE (logical statement). It could be source of mistakes.
When you use the pipe operator, you don't need to rewrite the data : `df %>% arrange(col_T)`